# ExtJs - reload store on expand

Tags: extjs, tree, store

How do I reload a store?

How do I pass the new corresponding path to the proxy (nodeParam)?

EDIT:

My tree has `name` and `path` and `children` attributes. However, since `children: []` are empty, there is no arrow shown to click on.

I want the arrows to be shown, and then request data waiting at `path` (/abc/def).

I read someone uses dummy data that gets deleted when the new request is made.

Comment: To reload the store use `store.load();`. Can't understand your second question.

Comment: Thanks. I have a node with `path: '/abc/def/'` and `children: []`. Because of empty children there is no arrow shown. But I want the arrow to be shown and then when clicking it, request the data waiting at `path` (`/abc/def`). How is that possible?

Comment: Try to use `expandable: true` at specified node.

Comment: No this did not help. One node now looks like this `{"name":"subfolder3","path":"\/subfolder3","leaf":false,"type":"folder","children":[], "expandable": true}`

Comment: Ok got it. Empty children is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty children `"childr‌​en":[]` lead to showing no arrow.

Comment: But thats a problem since I want to load new data when clicking on the arrow. I fixed it by only adding `children` when not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your answer to yourself means you've figured that out already. Anyway, it will work if you set "leaf" property to false and omit "children" property.